# Sublime Text 3 Gherkin auto completion not working

Tags: java, sublimetext, bdd, sublimetext3, gherkin

I have installed AndyHitchman's **"sublime-gherkin-auto-complete"** package. After installation I opened the feature file in ST3 and I could see the highlights properly but there were no suggestions for auto-completing gherkin phrases.
In my project the feature file contains the Gherkin phrases that are implemented in a "step definition" file.
Is there any way to force ST to autocomplete the phrases?

Comment: did you installed properly in Sublime text packages folder? @adi